# Can't connect after changing routers MAC address

Tags: ip-address, mac-address

I change my routers mac address regularly to change IPs so I can log into my different paypal accounts with worrying about getting them linked.

My IP is dynamic, but has a long lease so doesn't change every time I reset modem. I found out I could log into my routers admin panel and change the mac address there, and then after resetting the router and modem, the IP would be different.

But now when I change my mac address, and reset modem/router, the computer connects, but I can only access the routers default gateway, not the internet. I can now only access it through the mac addresses I've used in the past. I just cloned my mac address the first time, and then changed the last digits slightly to get a different IP, but this doesn't work now.

I'm with Virgin Media. Anybody know what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you. Some of ours Internet provider in our country put into "connection contract" just one MAC adress for access point /router. I had problem after storm with old router and i had to change it. In my situation - Connection problem caused by different Mac adress :(
pls check your connection terms and conditions and you will see ....

br

Comment: Yes, some ISPs require you to register your MAC address with their equipment, so you need to contact your ISP and have them update their system (also ask if there is a way for you to do it yourself through their website or something).

Answer (score 0):

This sort of thing is specific to the ISP, so my answer may not match your situation, but on Verizon FiOS, I've found that I'm limited to having only one DHCP lease (which is tied to a MAC address) at a time.  If I want to change the router's MAC address, I can't get a new lease until the old one expires (typically in an hour or so).  It's possible to manually relinquish a DHCP lease, which effectively makes it expire immediately, but most consumer router appliances don't provide a way to do that.

Change your MAC and wait a few hours.  See if you're able to connect then.